# How can I see the current download/upload speed for each wifi adapters?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-adapter, monitoring

I have 2 wifi adapters on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Both are connected to a wifi network. How can I see the current download/upload speed for each wifi adapters? Resource Monitor doesn't give a breakdown per wifi adapter.

---

2 wifi adapters both connected to a wifi network:

[image]

Resource Monitor doesn't give a breakdown per wifi adapter:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Window Task Manager displays the current download/upload speed for each wifi adapters:

[image]